# Histogram - Grade Distribution

Tags: java, charts, histogram

A grade text file was provide that has one integer number per line representing a
student’s grade in the class. These numbers are not sorted but they are bound between 0 and 100
(inclusive). Using an array, you must count the frequency of each grade value and print it to the
standard output as a horizontal histogram. You must also label the range of each histogram bar and
allow the user to indicate what size interval they would like the histogram to be made with.

This is my assignment and I'm stuck on how to label the range of each histogram bar and
allow the user to indicate what size interval they would like the histogram to be made with?

How can I fix my code?

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class GradeHistogram{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner gradeFile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("grades.txt"));
        int counter = 0;
        while (gradeFile.hasNextLine()) {
        gradeFile.nextLine();
        counter++;
        }
        int[] grades = new int[counter];
        System.out.println("Grades loaded!");
        System.out.println("What bucket size would you like?");
        Scanner output = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
           grades[i] = Integer.parseInt(output.nextLine());
            for ( i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            if (grades[i] > 0){
                System.out.print(i + "  | ");
                for (int j = 0; j < grades[i]; j++) {
                    System.out.print("[]");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ops!** Pay attention to the fact that you are currently reusing your variable `i` inside the loop. Your code may (and probably **will**) behave unexpectedly due to that. I also believe you are not parsing the file correctly.

You can use an auxiliary array to store the frequency of each grade. Initialize an empty array (fill it up with zeros) and then for each grade you just update the corresponding slot.

The code would be something like this:

```
    // 1. Generate your counting array
    //    (give it 101 slots to include all grades from 0 to 100)
    int gradeFrequency = new int[101];
    for (int j = 0; j < 101; j++) {
        gradeFrequency[j] = 0;
    }

    // 2. Parse the file and store the frequency of each grade
    while (gradeFile.hasNextLine()) {
       // get the grade and add 1 to its counter
        int grade = Integer.parseInt(gradeFile.nextLine());
        gradeFrequency[grade]++;
    }
```

After that, your `gradeFrequency` array will contain the frequency of each grade in the range 0 to 100.

When printing the histogram, you can ask the user to enter the interval they wish to see the histogram to, and then just print the corresponding frequencies from the array. The code for this would be something like:

```
    // Retrieve the interval the user wants to see
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the interval for the histogram (e.g. '0 100'):");
    int lowerBound = s.nextInt();
    int upperBound = s.nextInt();

    // Print the histogram title and 'column headers'
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("HISTOGRAM");
    System.out.println("Grade\tFrequency");

    // For each grade present in the interval, print out its 'label'
    // (the assigned grade)
    for (int i = lowerBound; i < upperBound; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + "\t");

        // For each time this grade was assigned to a student,
        // print an asterisk
        for (int j = 0; j < gradeFrequency[i]; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

*(Note that I didn't include any error handling for unexpected entries, like negative boundaries, start > end or an upper bound bigger than the array size; I leave it up to you!)*

The console after an example execution of this code would be something like this:

```
Enter the interval for the histogram (e.g. '0 100'):
5 11

HISTOGRAM    
Grade     Frequency
5         ***
6         *
7         ******
8         *
9         **
10        ******
11        ****
```

Could I make it clear or do you have any remaining questions? :)